# Duplication of data to redshift from kafka with spark streaming and spark redshift-connector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to set a data pipe line from Mysql binlogs to Redshift.I'm writing data to kafka from mysql binlogs(using a tool- cannedbeer,a fork from mypipe) and then using spark streaming to write those messages to redshift using spark redshift connector.The problem I'm facing is that same message was getting written multiple times onto redshift.Is this because of job failure in the foreachRDD method(side effect of writing to Redshift) of Dstream .Can u shed some light on this problem and how to solve it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Logging each part and seeing where it got duplicated? I'm using https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift to write to redshift from spark cluster without any issues.